# IActionContextAccessor not implemented

Tags: .net, dependencies, .net-8.0

I am using .NET 8 and facing problem that I am implementing AuthenticationHandler but facing the following error:

> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found on type 'TPAY.Boku.API.Middlewares.BokuApiAuthenticationHandler' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeOptions], Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory, System.Text.Encodings.Web.UrlEncoder, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock, TPAY.Boku.Services.Contracts.Customer.IUserService, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionContextAccessor, TPay.Core.Configuration.TPayConfiguration)'.

How should i implement it ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: As for the question - it is hard to tell how you should implement it if you don't show what you have tried and what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I was upgrading form .Net core 2.2 to .Net 8 after updating i am facing this error, in the previous version it was registering the iLoggerFactor by default so i am asking what should we do in.Net 8 @GuruStron

Comment: The error complains about `IActionContextAccessor`, why are you asking about `ILoggerFactory`?

Comment: Please share the `BokuApiAuthenticationHandler` and how do you use it.